# Two different icons open in launcher for Nautilus Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, unity, nautilus, launcher, icons

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 8.1.

When I open Files in launcher,two different icons pop up. By experimentation I found a solution(by unlocking it from launcher) for native Ubuntu(ext4) drives. But a different icon for NTFS drives from Windows still pops up. The screenshot of the desktop is below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKv7P.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to see NTFS partitions in Nautilus. What you shouldn't do though, is to click on the names, and then they get mounted, and you'll be tempted to read/write to them, which in the case of the C: drive (the 161GB name), can corrupt it.

Only if the 552GB is a shared NTFS partition, you might want to click on it, to mount it, so you CAN read/write to it.

To make sure that you don't have problems in a dual-boot configuration with Windows and Ubuntu is to do this...

**In Windows...**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup` # this will turn off fast startup
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` # this will disable hibernation